# AWS boto3 describe_config_rules() does not return rule description

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli, aws-config

I want to use the boto3 to view my config rules.

```
> import boto3
> client = boto3.client('config')     
> client.describe_config_rules()
```

The previous snippet returns the rule information, but does not include the filed 'Description' for rules with a long description. I can see the whole description in the AWS console, but boto3 does not retrieve the description. Why is that? Can we control this behaviour?

The CLI command

```
$ aws configservice describe-config-rules
```

also does not return the description

Thank you for your help!

I can see the description in the console
[image]

But `describe_config_rules` does not retrieve the description

```
response = client.describe_config_rules(
        ConfigRuleNames=[
            's3-bucket-logging-enabled-conformance-pack',
            ]
        )

'ConfigRules': [{'ConfigRuleArn': 'arn:aws:config:eu-central-1:xxxxxxxx:config-rule/aws-service-rule/config-conforms.amazonaws.com/config-rule',
                  'ConfigRuleId': 'config-rule-xxxx',
                  'ConfigRuleName': 's3-bucket-logging-enabled-conformance-pack',
                  'ConfigRuleState': 'ACTIVE',
                  'CreatedBy': 'config-conforms.amazonaws.com',
                  'Scope': {'ComplianceResourceTypes': ['AWS::S3::Bucket']},
                  'Source': {'Owner': 'AWS',
                             'SourceIdentifier': 'S3_BUCKET_LOGGING_ENABLED'}}],
```

...

Comment: Docs say it does return Description. Please provide an example of the output and screenshot from the console. maybe you are looking at different rules.

Comment: The config rule is part of a conformance pack. For rules that are not part of a conformance pack I do get the 'Description'. I edited the question to include the screenshot from the console and the output of describe_config_rules. Thank you!